# Send a message to and get back a response from a message driven bean

Tags: java, jms, message-queue

I'm trying to have a response back to a message driven bean but for an unknown reason I am not able to make work the communication correctly.

here is it the stateful bean. It send an object message and after create a temporary queue where receive the response.

```
@Stateful
public class BookingManagerBean implements BookingManagerBeanInterface
{

    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("jms/reservationProcessorQueueFactory")
    private JMSContext context;

    @Resource(mappedName = "jms/bookingProcessorQueueReceiver")
    private Queue bookingProcessorQueueReceiver;

    private Queue tempQueue;

    private JMSProducer messageProducer = null;
    private JMSConsumer messageConsumer = null;

    private String id_reservation = null;

    private Map<String,Object> map;

    @Override
    public String purchase()
    {                         

        try
        {
            sendMessageToBookingProcessorBean(object1, object2); // invia il messaggio contenente la prenotazione e il numero di punti utilizzati

            receiveMessageFromBookingProcessorBean(); // ricevi il messaggio dal MDB
        }
        catch(JMSException jmse)
        {
            System.err.println("An error occured " + jmse.toString());
            return (id_reservation);
        }

        return id_reservation;
    }

    private void sendMessageToBookingProcessorBean(Object object1, int object2) throws JMSException
    {                                  
        messageProducer = context.createProducer();

        messageProducer.send(bookingProcessorQueueReceiver,createMessageForBookingProcessorBean(object1, object2));
    }

    private Message createMessageForBookingProcessorBean(Object object1, int object2) throws JMSException
    {              
        ObjectMessage msg = context.createObjectMessage();

        tempQueue = context.createTemporaryQueue(); //create la queue temporanea dove sarà inviata la risposta
        messageConsumer = context.createConsumer(tempQueue);

        msg.setJMSReplyTo(tempQueue); 

        map = new HashMap<>();

        map.put("object1", object1);
        map.put("object2", object2);

        msg.setObject((Serializable) map);

        return msg;
    }

    private void receiveMessageFromBookingProcessorBean() throws JMSException
    {                
        Message msg = messageConsumer.receive();

        if(msg instanceof TextMessage)
        {
            TextMessage string = (TextMessage)msg;

            this.id_reservation = string.getText();
        }                
    }
}
```

Here is it the message driven bean

```
@MessageDriven(mappedName = "jms/bookingProcessorQueueReceiver", 
               activationConfig = {@ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "acknowledgeMode", propertyValue = "Auto-acknowledge"),
                                   @ActivationConfigProperty(propertyName = "destinationType", propertyValue = "javax.jms.Queue")
})
public class BookingProcessorBean implements MessageListener
{   
    @PersistenceContext
    private EntityManager em;

    @Inject
    @JMSConnectionFactory("jms/reservationProcessorQueueFactory")
    private JMSContext context;



    @Override
    public void onMessage(Message message)
    {                                  
        try
        {       
            ObjectMessage om = (ObjectMessage) message;

            map = (HashMap<String,Object>) om.getObject();


            System.out.println("Processing reservation...");


            sendIdReversationToBookingManagerBean(om.getJMSReplyTo(), "message response"); //prende la destinazione temporanea ed il messaggio
        }
        catch(UnsupportedEncodingException uee)
        {
            System.err.println("An error occured during the sending of the confirmation mail to " + reserv.getUsername().getEmail());
        }
        catch(MessagingException me)
        {
            System.err.println("An error occured during the sending of the email to " + reserv.getUsername().getEmail());
        }
        catch(JMSException e)
        {
            System.err.println("An error occured during the processing of the booking " + reserv.getId());
        }
    }


    private Message createMessageForBookingManagerBean(String message) throws JMSException
    {
        TextMessage msg = context.createTextMessage();

        msg.setText(message);

        return msg;
    }

    private void sendIdReversationToBookingManagerBean(Destination tempReceiverDestination, String message) throws JMSException
    {
        JMSProducer messageProducer = context.createProducer();

        messageProducer.send(tempReceiverDestination, createMessageForBookingManagerBean(id));
    }
}
```

I have tried to make some debug and I have noticed the program stuck in receive method. I'm pretty sure something doesn't work. May you help me?

Comment: I have used the method setJMSReplyTo to make sure I get the response in the temporary queue

Comment: The weird thing the code in mdb has not been excecuted...